# Get NSArray index number

Tags: objective-c, indexing, numbers, nsarray

```
self.listData = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"A",@"B",@"C", nil];
```

How can I get index numbers for listData items?

This code below is used to get listData items string:

```
c = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[listData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Something like...

```
NSUInteger index = [listData indexOfObject:@"A"];
```

From [the docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/indexOfObject%3a):

> **Return Value** 
>   The lowest index whose
>   corresponding array value is equal to
>   anObject. If none of the objects in
>   the array is equal to anObject,
>   returns NSNotFound.
>
> **Discussion** 
>   Objects are considered
>   equal if isEqual: returns YES.
>
> ** Important: If anObject is nil an exception is raised.**

Answer (score 0):

If you can guarantee that the strings in your array are unique, then using `indexOfObject:` will work. Otherwise, you'll need to use one of the indexesOfObjects* methods such as `indexesOfObjectsWithOptions:passingTest:` to get a set of all of the indexes containing the object you're interested in.